# Selecting two rows using SQL where they have not been compared before

Tags: sql, mysql, comparison

I have a database where users are presented with two items and choose the better of the two.  I only want to show users comparisons that they have not already made.  I have two tables:

**Item table**

```
+--------+---------+
| itemId |  name   |
+--------+---------+
|   1    | Dog     |
|   2    | Cat     |
|   3    | Fish    |
|   4    | Rat     |
+--------+---------+
```

**Vote table**

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------+
| voteId | betterItemId |  worseItemId | userId |
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------+
|    1   |       1      |       2      |    1   |
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------+
|    1   |       1      |       3      |    1   |
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------+
```

I need a (My)SQL query that gives me two random items for a user to compare, which the user has not already compared with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.itemId, a.name, b.itemId otherItemId, b.name othername
from item a
inner join item b on a.itemId < b.itemId
where not exists (
  select * from vote v
  where ((v.betterItemId = a.itemId and v.worseItemId = b.itemId)
     or  (v.betterItemId = b.itemId and v.worseItemId = a.itemId))
    and v.userId = 1234)   # << enter the userId here
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

- First generate all the a-b combinations, but use `a.id<b.id` to prevent duplicates (e.g. 1-2 and 2-1).
- Next for each combination of a-b, check that (in any permutation better-worse or worse-better) the item has not already been voted by userId (example of `1234` in query)
- order all results randomly using `order by rand()`
- use `limit 1` to get only 1 row
- In the select, show id and name for both items

To show it as two separate rows, the front end should be used for this.  But to do this purely in MySQL, a trick is required. The below is untested at the time of writing.

```
select ItemId, name
from
(
    select a.itemId, a.name, @b := b.itemId
    from item a
    inner join item b on a.itemId < b.itemId
    where not exists (
      select * from vote v
      where ((v.betterItemId = a.itemId and v.worseItemId = b.itemId)
         or  (v.betterItemId = b.itemId and v.worseItemId = a.itemId))
        and v.userId = 1234)   # << enter the userId here
    order by rand()
    limit 1
) c
union all
select itemId, name
from item d on d.itemId = @b
```

Comment: This is working nicely.  I should have specified in the question that I really could use two separate rows if possible, one for each item.  Is there any way to integrate this?

Comment: That would be trivial to achieve from a front end? It will be tricky using mySQL

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `not exists` clause to ensure the combination has not been voted on:

```
select  a.itemId
,       b.itemId
from    Items a
join    Items b
on      a.ItemId < b.ItemId
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Vote
        where   userId = 42
                and ((betterItemId = a.ItemId and worseItemId = b.ItemId)
                     or (worseItemId = a.ItemId and betterItemId = b.ItemId))
        )
order by
        rand()
limit   2
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost here - what is the logic behind this bit "JOIN Items b ON a.ItemId < b.ItemId"?

Comment: @Moyersy: it's a self join, the `ON` condition prevents selecting both `1,2` and `2,1`, which I assume presents the same choice to the end user